# AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account). GET https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/account 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs, backend, appwrite

Hopefully, you guys are doing well. I have an issue with the appwrite service. Here is the code.

```
client = new Client();
    account;







 constructor(){
        this.client.setEndpoint(String(import.meta.env.VITE_APPWRITE_URL).appWriteUrl)
.setProject(String(import.meta.env.VITE_APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID).appWriteProjectId);

        this.account = new Account(this.client);
    }






    async getCurrentUser(){
        try {
            return await this.account.get();
        } catch (error) {
            // throw error;
            console.log("Appwrite service :: getCurrentUser :: error", error);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And I got this error:

GET https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/account 401 (Unauthorized)

AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account).

Please, have a look and suggest me how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the server or client SDK?

If you are using the NodeJS SDK then you would need to provide an API key and ensure that the API key scope is set to allow this request.

If you are getting this error from the client SDK, then it may be because you don't currently have an active session. If you don't have an active session then you can use this error message to handle the next step which would be to prompt the user to login.

Comment: I am using React for the front end and appWrite as a backend.

Comment: Then it simply looks like the current user has not been authenticated or session has expired. This will happen on the first render when you load your app. It not cause for concern, just add a try catch and redirect the user to login when this happens.